# Making a simple line graph with NO core plot

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, graph

I need to make a line graph in my application to track data. I looked at core plot, and it seems WAY to complicated. Is there a simpler way to just make a line graph that can move horizontally and it will need to be able to add new segments. And not cause a huge memory overload because a lot will be added frequently, tho I could make it so they delete after a moth or something. So my question is basically : is there a easier method than core plot, and if Someone can lead me in the direction of being able to add more segments with custom data. Thanks in advance.

---

## Edit

I tried this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
    [super drawRect:rect];
    // find min and max values of data
    float max = -HUGE_VALF, min = HUGE_VALF;
    for (int i = 0; i < 0; i ++)
    {
        min = MIN(min, 0);
        max = MAX(max, 10);
    }
    
    // build path
    for (int i = 0; i < 0; i ++)
    {
        // line spacing is the distance you want between line vertices
       float x = i * 1;
        // scale y to view height
       float y = ((1 - min) / (max - min)) * self.bounds.size.height;

        if (i == 0)
        {
            CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, x, y);
        }
        else
        {
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, x, y);
        }
    }
    // stroke path (configure color, width, etc before this)
    CGContextStrokePath(nil);
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can draw it yourself using CoreGraphics.

In the `drawRect` of a UIView (or custom image context).

```
{ 
   // find min and max values of data 
   float max = -HUGE_VALF, min = HUGE_VALF;
   for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i ++)
   {
       min = MIN(min, data[i]); 
       max = MAX(max, data[i]);
   }

   // build path
   for (int i = 0; i < dataCount; i ++)
   {
       // line spacing is the distance you want between line vertices
       float x = i * lineSpacing;
       // scale y to view height 
       float y = ((data[i] - min) / (max - min)) * self.bounds.size.height;

       if (i == 0)
       {
           CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, x, y);
       }
       else
       {
           CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, x, y);
       }
   }
   // stroke path (configure color, width, etc before this)
   CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
}
```

This is very simple, but hopefully it gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: Put this in the view did load?

Comment: @user2701925 no this is drawing to a graphics context. Some place that has one. Probably subclass UIView and override drawRect

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea what you mean

Comment: @user2701925 maybe you should learn about those things before drawing graphs then. Sorry this is the scope of the question..

Comment: Ok, so figured out how to do draw rect on a view, and now I am guessing to put in this code that you gave me. Still a little lost tho. I got a bunch of errorsHabit Pal Group
Assigning to 'float' from incompatible type 'void'
Pal/drawView.m:40:27: Use of undeclared identifier 'lineSpacing'
Use of undeclared identifier 'data'
Use of undeclared identifier 'dataCount'

Comment: And most of these I got multiple times

Comment: The reason you got "undeclared identifier" is that you are using the code he gave you without understanding it. See how he has a variable "datacount"? That means that you need to make a variable called datacount and define it. You need to define all the variables his code uses before just plugging it in.

Comment: @user2701925 yeah, what data do you want to graph? My code doesnt know that

Comment: So could I put in a number?

Comment: @user2701925 yes the example just uses a "psuedo" c array of numbers. You could substitue an NSArray of NSNumbers or create a c array.